# Google Maps Not Showing on my Website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm currently working on adjustments for a project for a bank, and they need to show the bank location using google maps.

The problem is that the website was already made, and working over someone else's code is difficult for me.

The google maps is inside a file called contact.php, it has a contact form, and the google maps set as a background. I will just paste the Javascript API to see if there are any error

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD4Z5K4tM5FBXQH5R__XwqyPzRbQR-fIZY"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#btn_onlineb').css('color', '#6ca8cc');
        //set your google maps parameters
        var latitude = 15.299594,
            longitude = -61.387215,
            map_zoom = 8;

    
        //google map custom marker icon - .png fallback for IE11
        var is_internetExplorer11= navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('trident') > -1;
        var marker_url = ( is_internetExplorer11 ) ? 'img/pic_zumageo.png' : 'img/pic_zumageo.png';

        //define the basic color of your map, plus a value for saturation and brightness
        var main_color = '#acc8d4',
            saturation_value= -20,
            brightness_value= 5;

        //we define here the style of the map
        var style= [
            {
                //set saturation for the labels on the map
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                    {saturation: saturation_value}
                ]
            },
            { //poi stands for point of interest - don't show these lables on the map
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: "off"}
                ]
            },
            {
                //don't show highways lables on the map
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'labels',
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: "off"}
                ]
            },
            {
                //don't show local road lables on the map
                featureType: "road.local",
                elementType: "labels.icon",
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: "off"}
                ]
            },
            {
                //don't show arterial road lables on the map
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "labels.icon",
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: "off"}
                ]
            },
            {
                //don't show road lables on the map
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: "off"}
                ]
            },
            //style different elements on the map
            {
                featureType: "transit",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.government",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.sport_complex",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.attraction",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.business",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "transit",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "transit.station",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "landscape",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]

            },
            {
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.highway",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },

                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    { hue: main_color },
                    { visibility: "on" },
                    { lightness: brightness_value },
                    { saturation: saturation_value }
                ]
            }
        ];

        //set google map options
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            zoom: map_zoom,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
            styles: style,
        }
        //inizialize the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-container'), map_options);
        //add a custom marker to the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            map: map,
            visible: true,
            icon: marker_url,
        });

        //add custom buttons for the zoom-in/zoom-out on the map
        function CustomZoomControl(controlDiv, map) {
            //grap the zoom elements from the DOM and insert them in the map
            var controlUIzoomIn= document.getElementById('cd-zoom-in'),
                controlUIzoomOut= document.getElementById('cd-zoom-out');
            controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomIn);
            controlDiv.appendChild(controlUIzoomOut);

            // Setup the click event listeners and zoom-in or out according to the clicked element
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIzoomIn, 'click', function() {
                console.log("Plus: " + map.getZoom());
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1)
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUIzoomOut, 'click', function() {
                console.log("Minus: " + map.getZoom());
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)
            });
        }

        var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var zoomControl = new CustomZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);

        //insert the zoom div on the top left of the map
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(zoomControlDiv);

    })
```

Could you please tell me which CSS styles will show it as background please¿?

Answer (score 1):

At a first look you have comma in wrong place in javascript object  (remove the comma at the last entry of a object

```
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: map_zoom,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
        styles: style
    }
    ....
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        icon: marker_url
    });
```

You should check in browser  console for other runtime errors

Comment: Removing the comma from the last element  . .. work or there are others problems?

Comment: Other problems, even commenting my code and making everything from 0 gives the same error, maybe it has something wrong on the css styles?

Comment: By the way, the error fixeed itself alone WTF, idk what happened, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AlejandroMonzón  do you have removed the  comma  after the last attribute in the objects :.. ?   that was an blocking  error  for map

Comment: no that's the thing, i checked today the first unedited version and it just worked... lol, maybe it was google maps.

Comment: check in console .. becase the comma at the end of the lasta attribute is a blocking error  (have you change broswer or browser  version?)

Comment: I did remove it, but it did not work, then suddenly it worked the next day, could it just be google api being under maintenance?, thanks anyways it's solved now